# scroll to element when page is loaded get wrong element sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, scrollview

I have a page where there many are a loop of posts with description and images.

then I used this function to scroll to element

```
   $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".entry" + vm.note).offset().top + 200
               }, 1000);
```

the probleme is sometimes I scrolled to go element and sometimes not.
I dont know why.

PS: I using angularJS

Comment: Have you tried scrolling with ID's?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the DOMs are still rendering and it can't calculate the exact top distance from body/html to the element(".entry"+vm.note) you want to scroll.

You might try to put a delay before you execute your code using timeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".entry" + vm.note).offset().top + 200
               }, 1000);
}, 3000); //set it longer if it's still not scrolling
```